# Analyze playing Sound (Levels, Volume etc.) with minim

Tags: audio, minim

I thoroughly searched for how to analyze the playing sound with minim but found no good results.

I'm using the following Software:

- Eclipse Juno
- Java 1.7.0_21-b11
- Processing 2.0b9 Librarys
- Minim 2.0.2 library only

I think of it as opening the "currently active" system-line and printing the level to the console for example.

**A real example would be:**

- I have no sound-output at all, start my program and 0 gets printed in a loop
- I play a soundfile with windows media player for example and the level gets printed
- as I pause the music 0 gets printed again

I built myself an Adalight and connected my guitar to the computer.
Now I try to change the light color to red for example if I hit the strings. But because I use a multieffect device I can't analyse the Input (it works over a ASIO and doesnt show amplitude in system devices).

Comment: What precisely is the question here? It is currently very vague, and unlikely to solicit an answer.

Comment: The Question is: How do I print the level of the currently playing sound with minim?

Comment: What precisely do you define as 'level' here? I'm skimming through the minim documentation and it can probably do what you need. But we need some clarification.

Comment: Its not that important for me wich Information I visualize with my Adalight :) The first important Step I dont know how to do is to get Information about the currently playing sound in my Program. (take something else if you want: frequency, amplitude, gain, volume, whatever :) )